# Multiselect option with remove item

Tags: filter, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qlabel

I'm looking for a Qt/QML multiselect control that have a remove button.
I want to add a filter builder and I didn't find a good example or control for this purpose.

I can design token by myself. I'm just curious if someone already did that and can share it.

[Multi filter selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZjSi.png)

Thanks

Comment: You can take `GridView` as a base item and make with it whatever you want - multiselection etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple radio button for each option can do the job. If you do not include all these radio buttons under an exclusive group, a second click on these buttons deselects the option.

A click on the radio button includes selected option in the search results and second selection removes the option from the results.

An extra button which deselects all the radio buttons can also be added.

I don't intend to insult or disrespect you, but i think with radio buttons the task takes less time than posting this question.